# Which are the pin choices for powering and driving an audio amplifier with signal and power on raspberry pico pi

Tags: gpio, audio, pi-pico

I am using an audio amplifier,`PAM8302A` from *adafruit* [link](https://www.adafruit.com/product/2130), to power a 8ohm 1W speaker (small speaker) that is being driven by a `raspberry pi pico`. The amplifier has `A+` for the signal/audio input (not using the `A-`), and the DC/grnd input pins. (**the amp is a class D**)

I want to know which pins of the pico should drive the `audio+` input of the amplifier and which pins to choose for the DC input to power the amplifier. For the audio output from the pico is it any of the `GP` pins? Then for the powering of the amplifier is it `GP` pin or is it maybe the `3V3(OUT)` or some other pin? And to power the amp is that pin programmed to simply be 'on' the whole time by setting the pin to true at all times? (*specifically when is the 3V3(OUT) used and when is it not in comparison to the GP pins*)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Pico doesn't supply power (other than what your PSU may supply).

You can draw a small current from the 3.3V regulator (Max permissible current is 300mA).

If you want to run a high power peripheral YOU need to supply power.

The Pico has no analog output but can produce PWM (although what a PWM amplifier would do with this is unclear).

You would be better to seek something designed for PWM (or other digital signal) input.